# How can I produce a sorted export of a large BigQuery table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I would like to produce a sorted CSV export of a large BigQuery table in Google Cloud Storage. Currently to do this, we start with an unsorted table, then do a `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col1, col2` into another table, and then export that table to GCS. This works well, since the export seems to use the insertion order of the second table.

However, `ORDER BY` has limitations, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739857/587723) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25999187/587723). We get the dreaded "Resources exceeded during query execution." error when we try this on a sufficiently large table.

Is there another way to perform this?

Answer (score 4):

There are no guarantees that exported data will follow any particular order. I'd suggest to export the table and then sort it with other methods like those detailed in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/how-to-sort-big-files.

Since we are talking about a large export, you could pre-partition data before exporting (for example, by year) to help the external sorting algorithm.